# JavaFX "already set as root of another scene" exception when launching modal dialog a second time

Tags: javafx-2

I am building a simple JavaFX application that requires me to launch a modal window in front of my main application window.  Using the code below, I am able to launch the modal window 1 time and close it.  If I attempt to launch it again, I receive:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BorderPane[id=root, styleClass=root]is already set as root of another scene
```

I am using the Spring Controller/FXML View dependency injection method described here:
http://www.zenjava.com/2012/02/20/porting-first-contact-to-spring/

I am able to programatically create a scene and hide/display a simple dialog without using FXML / Spring Controller injection.  This works fine.

I am unable to explain the 'already set as root' exception, as I am creating a new Scene() each time the startButton is clicked.  The 1st Scene should have been destroyed whenever the modal window was closed the 1st time.

Relevant files are below.

MainTabPanel.java - The main view of my application.  This contains the 'startButton' that is clicked to launch the modal window.

The ActivePresentation Controller/View is injected as:
`@Inject private ActivePresentation activePresentation;`

Below is the initialize() method that attempts to launch the modal when startButton is clicked.

```
@FXML
 public void initialize()
 {
      availableReceiversIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("id"));
      availableReceiversFirmwareVersionColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firmwareVersion"));
      availableReceiversModelColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("model"));
      availableReceiversChannelColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("channel"));
      ObservableList<String> responseTypes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      responseTypes.add("Single Response Alpha");
      responseTypes.add("Single Response Numeric");
      responseTypeChoiceBox.setItems(responseTypes);

      startButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
      {
           @Override
           public void handle(ActionEvent e)
           {
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

                presentationResponseService.startPresentation();
                activePresentation.populateResponses(null);
                activePresentation.populateResults(null);

                Scene activePresentationScene = new Scene(activePresentation.getView());
                activePresentationScene.getStylesheets().add("styles.css");

                stage.setScene(activePresentationScene);
                stage.setTitle("Active Presentation");
                stage.showAndWait();
           }
      });
 }
```

The closeButton is defined in the modal dialog as follows.

```
closeButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
      {
           @Override
           public void handle(ActionEvent e)
           {
                presentationResponseService.closePresentation();
                Stage stage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close();
           }
      });
```

The Java based Spring configuration for the ActivePresentation bean and FXML loader are as follows.

```
@Bean
 public ActivePresentation activePresentation()
 {
      return loadPresenter("/fxml/ActivePresentation.fxml");
 }
```

FXML Loader

```
private <T> T loadPresenter(String fxmlFile)
 {
      try
      {
           FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
           loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fxmlFile));
           return (T) loader.getController();
      } catch (IOException e)
      {
           throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Unable to load FXML file '%s'", fxmlFile), e);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Seems, the stage is still under control of JFX (logic : you can try yo open it again), but you create a stage each time while previous is still alive, so, could you try to add stage.setScene(null) near stage.close(). Or use the same scene or the same stage each time?

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue when I had a pop-up window autowired. it was working the first time but when I close the pop-up window the second time, I was getting this error.
I managed by checking if the pop-up window had already a scene, see the below code:

```
if (window.getScene() == null) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(window);
    stage.setScene(scene);
} else {
    stage.setScene(window.getScene());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems, the stage is still under control of JFX (logic : you can try yo open it again).

And you create a stage each time while previous is still alive, so, could you try to add stage.setScene(null) near stage.close().

Or use the same scene or the same stage each time?

I don't see any bug in this part of JFX : node is the same, stages (and scenes in it) are different. So there are 2 ways : use only 1 stage+scene, or create different border pane instances each time.